# Share MY desktop and stream it to Silverlight/FLV?

Tags: .net, wpf, desktop-sharing

I'd like clients to see my desktop through a web app. They just need to see a real-time view of my desktop, they need not "interact" with it.

In line with it, perhaps also a webcam/voice stream to go with it.

So my website will contain the following:
1. My Desktop
2. My face (through webcam)
3. My voice (through a mic)

My personal skill set are mostly .NET (asp.net/c#) but I can get some help from my team for WPF/Silverlight. Any ideas on how to start with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the mic and camera access, check this out: [Accessing Web Camera and Microphone](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/graphics/webcam-and-mic/accessing-web-camera-and-microphone)

The desktop sharing part is not as straightforward as the other features. Check out these links:

- [How to take a snapshot of the screen in SL 4?](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/163378.aspx/1/10)
- [Streaming webcam & desktop em Silverlight](http://pontonetpt.org/blogs/ruimarinho/archive/2010/02/16/streaming-webcam-amp-desktop-em-silverlight.aspx) (english version at the bottom).

You'll need to run in OOB mode with elevated trust in order to interact with a COM object which will be responsible for the screen capturing.

You could make two different applications: one for the presenter that requires more privileges, and another one for the clients, which would run as a simple web app.